# What is the advantage of passing Anti-Forgery Token as header info

Tags: asp.net-mvc

just come across a article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/passing_anti-forgery_token_to_mvc_actions_using_ajax_post/archive/2014/06/30/passing-anti-forgery-token-to-mvc-actions-using-ajax-post.aspx

they are passing Anti-Forgery Token as header info.

the above article show how to pass Anti-Forgery Token as header info but why people pass it as header. is there any specific need or reason?

it will be more secure to passing Anti-Forgery Token as header info ? need clarification.

what is the meaning of `Constants.AntiForgeryTokenSalt`  `(Html.AntiForgeryToken(Constants.AntiForgeryTokenSalt) )`

### here small snippet

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   { %>
    <%: this.Html.AntiForgeryToken(Constants.AntiForgeryTokenSalt)%>

    <%-- Other fields. --%>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<% } %>


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Salt = Constants.AntiForgeryTokenSalt)]
public ActionResult Action(/* ... */)
{
    // ...
}
```

thanks